# Unable to install iceberg extensions for pyspark and use MERGE INTO

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-iceberg

I have a python virtual environment in which I have added pyspark v3.4.1. I have run the following command to install the iceberg package-

```
spark-sql --packages org.apache.iceberg:iceberg-spark-runtime-3.2_2.12:1.3.0\
--conf spark.sql.extensions=org.apache.iceberg.spark.extensions.IcebergSparkSessionExtensions \
--conf spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkSessionCatalog \
--conf spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog.type=hive \
--conf spark.sql.catalog.local=org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog \
--conf spark.sql.catalog.local.type=hadoop \
--conf spark.sql.catalog.local.warehouse=$PWD/warehouse
```

It raises the following error-

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/AnsiCast

I am able to load the packages if I remove the extensions config, but am unable to use the MERGE INTO function in my SQL queries. What could be causing this error?

Answer (score 3):

You must use :

`org.apache.iceberg:iceberg-spark-extensions-3.4_2.12`

`org.apache.iceberg:iceberg-spark-runtime-3.4_2.12`

instead of:

`org.apache.iceberg:iceberg-spark-runtime-3.2_2.12`

Comment: the version change works